# Create wordpress user remotely using email I provide

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to create a wordpress user with contributor privelages, remotely. However, I would like to also create their wordpress account using an email that I manipulate by using their id (from login on my site) and @example.com. So it would essentially be: id#@example.com. I am very new to programming. I have looked and looked and just continue to scratch my head. What would be best practice for doing this? Any examples, resources, explanations would be appreciated!

I was thinking of creating a link in their account page that when the logged in user clicks it it will redirect them to a page that will create their user account within wordpress framework. They would have to be logged into my site to access.

Comment: "I would like to create a wordpress user with contributor privelages, remotely. " define "remotely". I think you should elaborate more on what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a link in their account page that when the user clicks it it will redirect them to a page that will create their user account within wordpress framework.

Comment: "in their account page" so they have already a wordpress account?

Comment: account page on my site. they do not have a wp acct at this point. i want to create remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do the email portion of your question. Although, I would like to know how to meld the two together. However, if you are needing unique emails for wordpress you can by-pass this required section (required if using wp dashboard to create user). I found this recently.

You could simply:

```
$user_name = //however you get your unique identifier this will be their screen name

$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $user_email );
    wp_update_user(array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'role' => 'contributor'
    ));

}
```

If your users actually do have an email account on your server and you want them to receive emails from wordpress.. this will not fix your situation.

Comment: This will do, for now. I do not require the email. I thought I had to provide an email to  create account in wp. Like you... I would also like to know how to set that email.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do this. the cleanest would probably at the moment be to use the Wordpress API together with JWT [authentication](https://medium.com/@oprearocks/video-enable-jwt-authentication-for-the-wordpress-rest-api-26120e4a232e).

Here is an easier solution. On the Remote Wordpress Installation you stick something like this into your functions.php

```
function remote_create_user() {
    $token = (isset($_GET['token'])) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['token']) : '';
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['action']) : '';

    //this is not particularly secure, but let's assume your wordpress page has https which should encrypt the url...
    //im just setting some random string to compare to
    if ($token != '712031ff105541219fcc741d99a9addd' || $action != 'createuser') {
        return;
    }

    $username = sanitize_text_field($_GET['username']);
    $email = sanitize_text_field($_GET['email']);

    //making sure the user doesn already exist
    $user_id = username_exists($username);
    if (!$user_id and email_exists($email) == false) {
        $random_password = wp_generate_password($length = 12, $include_standard_special_chars = false);
        //creating the user
        $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $random_password, $email);
        if ($user_id) {
            //here you could send the user a welcome mail. if you want, include the password in the mail or just make him press the "forgot password" button
            //wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            echo "User created";
        }
    } else {
        echo "User already exists.";
    }
}

add_action('init', 'remote_create_user');
```

On the system you want to send the command from, you can then do something like this (on the serverside, you can't to this from the browser, because the "authentication" token will be visible in the javascript...

```
$createuser = file_get_contents('https://yourdomain.com/?token=712031ff105541219fcc741d99a9addd&action=createuser&username=test3&email=test3@test.com');
//depending on the result in $createuser, give an error message or redirect him to your wordpress login page or something
```

i hope this gives you some ideas.

Edit: Aboves init function is missing a wp_die() at the end. we dont want the whole page rendered here. also, this is just a quick & dirty solution.
Look into Wordpress Rest API or also custom endpoints.

Comment: but how can I make the email id#@example.com?

Comment: what do you mean by id# ? literally?  what's with the #
id number? is this a placeholder?
reading the upper answer: you do need to provide an email address, but the email doesnt have to exist.

Comment: just create a random, nonexisting, mail address: $email=uniqid()."@mydomain.com";